# Why is runas working even with a nonexistent user

Tags: windows, runas

I wondered why running this command is working (none of the computer or the user are existing) :

```
> runas /user:I_do_not_exist\me_neither /netonly cmd.exe
```

There is a password prompt, but you can enter whatever you want.

If i'm running `whoami` on the new cmd, the current user is the original user (which exist), but on the window I can see a **running as I_do_not_exist\me_neither**

By the way, this one is not working :

```
> runas /user:I_do_not_exist\me_neither cmd.exe
Enter the password for I_do_not_exist\me_neither:
Attempting to start cmd.exe as user "I_do_not_exist\me_neither" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - cmd.exe
1326: Incorrect password or username.
```

I'm using Windows 10 21H2 and I'm not in an Active Directory network.

Comment: Error message is clear: `1326: Incorrect password or username`.

Comment: Without the netonly argument yes, It is the behavior that I would expect. But with netonly, it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found why `runas` has this behavior while digging further:

- As we can see [here](https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Detecting+Mimikatz+Use+On+Your+Network/19311/):

> Windows doesn't try to authenticate to the Microsoft.com domain to
> launch the process.  It assumes that the credentials are correct,
> calculates the hashes and stores them in memory for future use.  At
> some point in the future, if you try to access a resource on that
> domain it will automatically use windows single sign on capabilities
> to "PASS THE HASH" to the remote system and log you in.  But until you
> try to access the remote network, the passwords just sit there in
> memory.

- It is possible to confirm it we take look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) of the function `CreateProcessWithLogonW` (which should be used under the hood of `runas`). This function take a parameter `dwLogonFlag`, and if we specify `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY` (i.e `/netonly` with `runas`), the docs says that:

> The system does not validate the specified credentials. Therefore, the
> process can start, but it may not have access to network resources.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 1):

It's "working" because the unknown user-account is ignored,
so the command is started with your own account.

The question of why is this not a hard error should be asked of Microsoft. Your second example does show a hard error,
so the first example is probably a missing check (bug) somewhere
in the `runas` command when `netonly` is specified.

To verify, you could use
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).